# Deserializando JSON em PHP

Tags: php, json

Boa tarde, estou com algumas dúvidas no PHP. Tenho um arquivo PHP responsável apenas por apresentar um CPF no formato JSON, e com outro arquivo estou tentando consumir esses dados para apresentar na tela.

Arquivo de consumo cpf.php apresenta os dados dessa forma:

```
[{"id":"1","cpf":"098712321321","score":"400",]
```

Estou tentando fazer um foreach nesse JSON para imprimir os dados mas está dando um erro.

Arquivo de consulta,serasaService.php:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>Api</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $json_file = file_get_contents("http://localhost/motora-proj/cpf.php");
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($json_str as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <th><?php echo $e; ?></th>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($json_str as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Erro que está sendo apresentado:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/motora-proj/serasaService.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/motora-proj/serasaService.php on line 28

Podem me ajudar por gentileza? Obrigado!

Comment: O JSON está mal formado.

Answer (score 6):

O formato desse JSON está errado, deveria ser assim:

```
{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}
```

como ele está com o formato errado, o `json_decode` está retornando `NULL`, é importante fazer um tratamento de erros antes do `foreach`, como está usando php, pode usar o `is_array()` em uma condicional antes do `foreach`

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Api</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $json_file  = file_get_contents( 'http://localhost/motora-proj/cpf.php' );
      $json_str   = json_decode( $json_file, true );
    ?>

    <?php if ( is_array( $json_str ) || is_object( $json_str ) ): ?>      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <?php foreach ( $json_str as $e => $key ): ?>          
            <th><?php echo $e; ?></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          <?php foreach ( $json_str as $e => $key ): ?>            
            <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <?php else: ?>
      <!-- mensagem de erro -->
    <?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Seu *JSON* está mal formado e são duas as possibilidades de reparo para ele.

1 - `[{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}]`

2 - `{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}`

No primeiro caso o *JSON* representa uma array cujo os elementos são objetos.
No segundo caso o *JSON* representa apenas um objeto.

Para cada um dos casos é necessário uma abordagem diferente.

## Primeiro caso:

Para responder vou simplificar o seu código removendo as tags de *HTML*, mantendo o código em *PHP* com uma diferença o *JSON* vai ser colocado inline e impresso:

```
<?php
    $json_file = '[{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}]';
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    print_r($json_str);
?>
```

resultando em:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cpf] => 09871204922
            [score] => 400
        )

)
```

Significando que objeto decodificado é uma array cujo o primeiro elemento também é um array. Nesse caso deve-se iterar pelo array mais externo para buscar as chaves e valores do elemento interno:

```
<?php
    //Aumentado a complexidade do JSON
    $json_file = '[{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"},{"id":"2","cpf":"09848269111","score":"250"}]';
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    foreach($json_str as $item){
      foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " ". $value . PHP_EOL;
      }
    }
?>
```

Que vai resultar em:

```
id 1
cpf 09871204922
score 400
id 2
cpf 09848269111
score 250
```

Fazendo o reparo do seu código para o primeiro caso:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Api</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $json_file = '[{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"},{"id":"2","cpf":"09848269111","score":"250"}]';
    //file_get_contents("http://localhost/motora-proj/cpf.php");
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                  foreach ($json_str[0] as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <th><?php echo $e; ?></th>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach($json_str as $item){
                  ?> <tr>
                <?php foreach ($item as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?><tr><?php 
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Irá resultar em:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Api</title>
</head>

<body>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                                    <th>id</th>
                                    <th>cpf</th>
                                    <th>score</th>
                            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>09871204922</td>
                                    <td>400</td>
                <tr> <tr>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>09848269111</td>
                                    <td>250</td>
                <tr>            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

## Segundo caso:

No segundo caso o JSON representa apenas um objeto sendo mais fácil iterar sobre suas propriedades bastando iterar diretamente sobre o objeto:

```
<?php 
    $json_file = '{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}';
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    print_r($json_str);
?>
```

Resultando em:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [cpf] => 09871204922
    [score] => 400
)
```

Bastando iterar diretamente sobre o objeto:

```
<?php 
    //Nesse caso não tem como aumentar a complexidade do objeto sem refatorar o código
    $json_file = '{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}';
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    foreach ($json_str as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . " ". $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Resultado em:

```
id 1
cpf 09871204922
score 400
```

Fazendo o reparo para esse segundo caso ao código da pergunta:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Api</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $json_file = '{"id":"1","cpf":"09871204922","score":"400"}';
    //file_get_contents("http://localhost/motora-proj/cpf.php");
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($json_str as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <th><?php echo $e; ?></th>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($json_str as $e => $key) {
                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Que irá resultar em:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Api</title>
</head>

<body>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                                    <th>id</th>
                                    <th>cpf</th>
                                    <th>score</th>
                            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>09871204922</td>
                                    <td>400</td>
                            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```